# Using Merge in Oracle for updating a parent table using Joins

Tags: oracle

I have a SQL statement as below, I couldn't execute the statement in Oracle as it doesn't support Joins in Update. I have tried using updating using a temp table and completed the job, however, I would like to use the Merge statement and failed to write the code.
Let me know if there is a possibility in Oracle use joins in an update which doesn't add any performance overhead.

```
 UPDATE A SET 
       YearStartPD = B.PERIOD_CODE,
    YearEndPD  = A.PERIOD_CODE,
    PY_YearStartPD = C.PERIOD_CODE,
    PY_YearEndPD = A.PY_WeekEndPD
FROM dbo.DIM_TIME A                  
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        select PERIOD_CODE,WEEK_PERIOD_CODE,YEAR_CODE from dbo.DIM_TIME 
WHERE WEEK_PERIOD_CODE = '01'
    ) B ON  B.Year_Code = A.Year_Code
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select PERIOD_CODE,WEEK_PERIOD_CODE,YEAR_CODE from dbo.DIM_TIME 
 WHERE WEEK_PERIOD_CODE = '01'
    ) C ON  C.Year_Code = A.Year_Code - 1
```

Comment: Oracle does support joins in update, but some (obvious) conditions must be met.  Oracle needs to know in advance that the join will produce only one row in each of B and C for every row of A (otherwise there is ambiguity). It needs to know that in advance, through `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`) constraints or indexes. In your case, for example, is `YEAR_CODE` unique in the table aliased as `C`? If it is not, **which** `C.PERIOD_CODE` should be used for update?

Comment: I usually write a query that gives me the end goal for the rows I want updated in the target table. Once I have that and have vetted the results, it is pretty trivial to wrap it in a merge statement - your query goes in "USING", then you match your key in the "ON" and set your updated fields in the "WHEN MATCHED UPDATE . .." part. Key thing is to make sure the query returns 0 or 1 row for any given key into your target table. Otherwise, how is Oracle supposed to know which row you want to use for the update?